# can't access Textbox value which is in gridview control on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have taken 3 text-boxes in grid view. I want to access all the 3 text-boxes value in single label on button click event.
ASP code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
        CssClass="style1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="342px" Width="548px">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField ApplyFormatInEditMode="True" DataField="IName" HeaderText="Item Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="Price" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="txtqty" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Text="Enter Quantity" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtqtys" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" OnTextChanged="TextBox_Changed"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);" AutoPostBack="true"
                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckChanged" Text="Select" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)" AutoPostBack="True"
                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckChanged" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
<asp:Label ID="lbltxtqty" runat="server" Text="txtqty" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnsubmit_Click" />
```

C# code:

```
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            lbltxtqty.Visible = true;
            lbltxtqty.Text = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("txtqtys")).Text;
        }
}
```

so please tell me the write code for it.

Comment: remove !ispostback condition

Comment: ok.let me check whether it works or not..

Comment: No dhaval..it doesn't work. i made it autopostback false.

Comment: maybe use javascript?

Comment: please give your error message..

Comment: dhaval.. it's not showing error but text box is blank and label is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

You are "Contradicting" your own `aspx` and `code behind` code. Why I am saying this is because, check you Label Mark-up & button click event handler:-

```
<asp:Label ID="lbltxtqty" runat="server" Text="txtqty" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
```

Here you are setting labels `Visible` property to `true` which is of no use because its by default true. Now, see your button click event you are trying to make it visible by using `lbltxtqty.Visible = true;`, So obviously your mark-up should first look like this:-

```
<asp:Label ID="lbltxtqty" runat="server" Text="txtqty" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

Because, you must be needing that when Page loads.

Now, comes your button click event. Do you know the `Page Life Cycle` of ASP.NET? When button click event is fired that's an obvious PostBack request so what is the Point of checking `IsPostBack` property there? Remove this code and it should work. Change your button click handler as follows:-

```
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbltxtqty.Visible = true;
    lbltxtqty.Text = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("txtqtys")).Text;
}
```

Comment: I did changes as per your suggestion but, it does not work. the label doesn't show anything.                                               lbltxtqty.Text = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("txtqtys")).Text; do you think this code is write as per the column added in grid view, means its row no row[0]

Comment: @PratikPatani - `Rows[0]` means you are trying to fetch the textbox value of first row. Also, what you are doing on `TextBox_Changed` event? If you are not doing anyhing, remove it.